# Knockoutjs native template - To create url

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

How to create a url using knockout js ***native*** templating.

```
<a href="http://" title="Visit site">
    <span data-bind="text: site"></span>
</a>
```

say the expression

```
<span data-bind="text: site">
```

substitute `www.xyz.com`. I am looking a way to prefix it with `http://`.

So, something like

```
<a href="http://${site}" title="Visit site">
```

which may work with jQuery templating. In essence, I wonder we always need `<span>, <li>` etc to output the text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using the data-bind with the attr binding. You can use plain javascript in the data-bind, so also you can use default concatenation

```
<a data-bind="attr: {'href':  'http://' + $data.site}, text: 'visit site'"></a>
```

`data-bind` can be done on practically everything, as long as it is rendered by the DOM. So you can put it on `<a>` tags, or whatever you want to use